# Proxy server to redirect blocked page request in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, proxy, http-proxy

I am using code from https://github.com/inaz2/proxy2 .However I want the proxy server to be able to use 2 network interfaces and switch between the 2 depending on the page body. eg. If the page body has content like "Access Denied" (my college has blocked a ton of sites) I want it to use another network interface (eg mobile phone usb tethered) . Is it possible to edit the response_handler function of the code to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not proxy's matter. I recommend configuring the routing table.